# MaxImage2 with scrollHorz effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle, maximage2

I'm using [MAXIMAGE 2](http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/) to make simple image slideshow. I try to use horizontal scroll effects ( i.e. `fx:scrollHorz` ). The JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/jofb4o4s/).

The problem is, the animation transition does not happen. It goes directly to 2nd slide without animation. Is this a bug of MAXIMAGE 2?

HTML:

```
<!-- Maximage / Cycle -->
<div id="maximage">
    <img src="http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/2.0/lib/images/demo/coalesse.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/2.0/lib/images/demo/wall_portrait.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/2.0/lib/images/demo/laughing.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/2.0/lib/images/demo/pattern.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/2.0/lib/images/demo/roof_shooting.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/2.0/lib/images/demo/man.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/2.0/lib/images/demo/coffee_shop.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/2.0/lib/images/demo/gas_station.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var imgs = $('#maximage img');
    imgs.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
    $('#maximage').html( imgs );

    $('#maximage').maximage({
        cycleOptions: {
            fx: 'scrollHorz',
            speed: 3000
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To make `scrollHorz` work without `fillElement` config, I have to add `cssTransitions: false` in the Maximage 2, as follow:

```
$(function() {
    var imgs = $('#maximage img');
    imgs.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
    $('#maximage').html( imgs );

    $('#maximage').maximage({
        cycleOptions: {
            fx: 'scrollHorz',
            speed: 3000
        },
        cssTransitions: false
    });
});
```

Not sure if it is a bug of MaxImage 2.